# How to disable Lock Screen in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen

I have `Windows 10 (Build 14295) Pro`. How to disable Lock Screen? I googled it, but there is no solution.

I tried [this](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/6567-lock-screen-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html). It does not work for me.

Comment: "It does not work for me" did you get an error message? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Is your computer on a domain (at work)?

Comment: @DavidPostill I did settings from link, but I see Lock screen when do Win + L

Comment: @CharlieRB no, I have no any domain